# I can't post on server?

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

***JAVASCRIT, REACT, Node.js***
As you can see from the javascript code I am trying to add some on the server-side using method post but it can not post on the server. What I can change on my code.**

```
        const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const { MongoClient, ServerApiVersion, ObjectId } = require('mongodb');
require('dotenv').config()
const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(express());
                app.post('/items', async (req, res) => {
                    const newItem = req.body;
                    console.log(newItem);
                    const result = await laptopCollection.insertOne(newItem);
                    res.send(result);
                })
```

**I think I am missing in middleware**

```
    app.use(cors());
app.use(express());
```

Comment: First of all, `app.use(express());` is not needed. And from your code snippet, `laptopCollection` is not imported.

Answer (score 0):

**I think correct middleware is:**

```js
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())
```

**Post with async function**

```js
async function run() {
    try {
        await client.connect();
const laptopCollection=client.db('database_name').collection('collection_name');

       app.post('/items', async (req, res) => {
                    const newItem = req.body;
                    console.log(newItem);
                    const result = await laptopCollection.insertOne(newItem);
                    res.send(result);
                })
        // Add New Post
    } finally {
        // await client.close();
    }
}
run().catch(console.dir);
```

Answer (score 0):

`app.use(express())` function can't parses incoming JSON requests and also can't puts the parsed data in `req.body.To` solve the problem write the function as

```
app.use(express.json())
```

You also forget to import `async function`. You need to provide this codes:

```
async function run() 
{
  try {
    await client.connect();
    const laptopCollection=client.db('database_name').collection('collection_name');
  app.post('/items', async (req, res) => {
    const newItem = req.body;
    console.log(newItem);
    const result = await laptopCollection.insertOne(newItem);
    res.send(result);
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the correct way is:

```js
app.use(cors())
app.use(express.json())
```